# How I can change value varible in a file in another file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, global-variables, module.exports

I want to change value variable in an index.js in another file, but i can't do that and this is my code example

**index.js**

```
   var length = 0;
   client.commands.get('join').excute(length);
```

**anotherfile.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'join',
    description: "",
    excute(length){
       length++;
    }
```

length in *index.js* is + 1 = 2, but length in *anotherfile.js* is not

> I imported anotherfile.js to index.js

So how i can change value in length variable

Thank you so much and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because JavaScript doesn't pass variables with primitive data types, such as an integer, through its reference to other functions, but rather creates a whole new variable with a different memory address. The only way you can mutate the original memory location is if you're passing in an array or object, which JavaScript will then pass in a pointer to the original memory location, ie "reference", to the function.

So you'd have to change the datatype of `length` to an object, and add the value/length of the object as a property. The `excute` function would then just access that property and increment it like so:

**index.js**:

```
const obj = { length: 0 }

client.commands.get('join').excute(obj);
```

**anotherFile.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'join',
    description: "",
    excute(obj){
       obj.length++;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, you have to pass the whole object, otherwise if you just pass the obj.length, it will simply copy the value and create a whole new variable set to that value.

Comment: omg it's working
thank you so much <3

Comment: anytime mate ;)